# Truncated speech-to-text output from wav file with SpeechRecognition recognize_google()

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have speech audio files in wav format that are 60 seconds each. However, the output gets truncated and only captures about 15% of the length. I have tried this both in my local Jupyter Notebook but also through Google Colab. According to the documentation, this request is below the threshold of the API. What am I doing wrong or how can I get around this limitation?

```
# select a recognizer session
# recognize_google() : Google Web Speech API
r = sr.Recognizer()

interview = sr.AudioFile('sample.wav')
with interview as source:
  print('Ready...')
  r.pause_threshold = 2
  audio = r.record(source, duration=60)

type(audio)
transcription = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en_CA')
print(transcription)
```

Comment: Put try and except block inside r.recognize_google() or remove language may be it can work!

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I guess should clarify that I'm not getting an error per se, but rather the recognizer is not computing the entire audio file. Could you clarify where exactly I should put the try and exceptblocks?

The output currently looks something like this


`Ready...
information we want a baller or persons also for personal safety like LeBron houses his bases the same thing when we contact the other team like`
but the spoken audio contains far more content after the text output finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code and if output still same as old you can ident try and except block or  change `pause_threshold` value

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile("sample.wav") as source:
    print("Ready")
    r.pause_threshold = 0.6 
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Error {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code -- unfortunately I ran it and it is not outputting any errors. I adjusted the following parameters to hopefully catch anything in the recording but no luck: `energy_threshold = 50`, `pause_threshold = 0.1`, `phrase_threshold = 0.1`, `operation_timeout = None`, `non_speaking_duration = 0`.